# Cassandra node.js driver does not accept dash separated string

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-node-driver

I am using [this](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver) driver as a bridge between cassandra and my node js app. Everything seems to work fine till now except following issue:

**Issue**
I have a column of type varchar, when i am inserting a string which has dash (-) in it then cassandra throws error`String didn't validate.`.

I am using batch statement which is like following

```
var queryset_insert_user = {
    query: query_insert_user,
    params: query_insert_user_params,
    hints:[ dataTypes.varchar, dataTypes.varchar, dataTypes.varchar, dataTypes.varchar,
    dataTypes.varchar, dataTypes.varchar, dataTypes.varchar]
}
```

where varchar is

```
var dataTypes = {};
dataTypes.varchar = 0x000d;  //couldn't find how to get this from API itself so just copied value from types.js of cassandra driver.
```

Batch statement is

```
var batchQueries = [queryset_insert_iidMetadata, queryset_insert_user];
client.batch(batchQueries,__queryOptions(), function(err, result){
       // getting err here...
});
```

Input parameters are:

```
query2 params are = ["4fde84c173232d25641db25ba1b0","+0012255446633",["1415957771074"],"CGFnzVSuGwkOrVI","NEW","+001","53a985bd-bc28-3768-a1ea-e366409cb996"]
```

**Note**
I have attempted to use hints when i saw [this](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql/issues/112) issue.

**How to solve this error**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DataStax Node.js driver for Cassandra, the parameter hints are passed in the query options:

```js
// Queries with the parameters
const queries = [ queryset_insert_iidMetadata, queryset_insert_user ];
// Parameter hints are passed with the rest of the queryOptions
client.batch(queries, {hints: [hintForIidMeta, hintForUser]}, callback);
```

In any case, [the **recommended** way is to use prepared statements](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#prepare-your-queries), that way the parameter mapping would be accurate:

```js
await client.batch(queries, { prepare: true })
console.log('Data updated on cluster');
```

Answer (score 3):

After adding the option `prepare: true`, the string containing dash can be inserted into cassandra nomally.

Here is the code from cassandra node driver repo:

```
// Use query markers (?) and parameters
const query = 'UPDATE users SET birth = ? WHERE key=?'; 
const params = [ new Date(1942, 10, 1), 'jimi-hendrix' ];
// Set the prepare flag in the query options
client.execute(query, params, { prepare: true })
  .then(result => console.log('Row updated on the cluster'));
```